# How can i change QStackWidget page index with button in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am currently working in Qt Designer and i am trying to make button change the index of QStackWidget with click signal.

I entered signal editor mode and connected Button to QStackWidget, This is what i got:

[image]

As you see in the picture, `setCurrentIndex(int)` is grayed out, If i choose any signal from QPushButton, there is nothing associated with changing page.

**Sorted Question:**

How can i change the page in QStackedWidget using a button? (In Qt Designer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible directly with Qt Designer, because `QButton` click signal doesn't send any index or argument, and `setCurrentIndex(int)` need an argument to chose change the index.
You have to do it using signal/slot in C++ code, or use an other widget like `QSpinBox` which emit a signal with an integer argument.

Comment: Im using pyQt bindings whenever i finish code, Is there any Qt code for that? so i will edit it when modified.